# Array of strings as an input

Tags: toloka

How to use input with "array of strings" in html when designing a Toloka task? I suppose some special syntax or extra formatting is required but I am confused about how to apply it.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a "string array" type in the input specification, separate elements in array
(https://yandex.com/support/toloka-requester/concepts/pool_csv.html#pool_csv__string) by a comma (,).

To upload a task with HTML (https://yandex.com/support/toloka-requester/concepts/t-components/html.html)

In the task interface put the name of the input data field in triple curly brackets. For example: {{{html}}}. Before uploading a task, make sure that all quotation marks in the formatted text are escaped (https://yandex.com/support/toloka-requester/concepts/pool_csv.html?lang=en#pool_csv__structure).